# Conditional formatting with QUERY result in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with 1 sheet of software version an another sheet of installation records. I want to do a conditional formatting that compares the version of in installation (on column `F`) to its know latest version number on another sheet (`'Software Versions'`).

### Current Solution

I came up with this formular initially:

```
=AND(F2<>"", F2=G2)
```

It works. But I need to maintain a column of QUERY results on G2:

```
=QUERY('Software Versions'!$A$1:$B$8, "Select B where A='" &D4& "' LIMIT 1")
```

### Problem

Now I want to remove the G2 row altogether. I came up with this combined query:

```
=AND(F2<>"", F2=QUERY('Software Versions'!$A$1:$B$8, "Select B where A='" &D4& "' LIMIT 1"))
```

But I cannot save it because it is an "Invalid Formula":

[image]

Any way to actually do it?

Comment: This looks to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/289691). What do you mean by "But I need to maintain a column of QUERY results on G2"?

Comment: It means I am maintain a "G2" column purely for conditional format. It works but it is ugly. Thus I want to remove it from my sheet while maintaining the conditional format.

Comment: G2 is a cell reference, that means that it returns a single/scalar value while QUERY apparently returns an array of values, the column header and the value, but I think fixing this will not resolve the problem. Create a demo spreadsheet with sample input data and the expected result.

Comment: I think I found the major issue. Formula in conditional formatting don't seems to support worksheet reference. A version of my formula works if I somehow don't reference range from another sheet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try use this formula:

`=AND(F2<>"", F2=IFERROR(QUERY(INDIRECT("'Software Versions'!$A$1:$B$8"), 
"Select B where A='" &D4& "' LIMIT 1 label B ''"),""))`

I was able to make conditional formatting with this formula.

## Improvements

1. Use `indirect` to address another sheet
2. Use `label B ''` to prevent header appear as query result
3. Use `iferror(..., "")` to be sure no error occurs when no data is found with `query`

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to the good old VLOOKUP function for my conditional formattings.

The syntax is `VLOOKUP(valueOrCell, sourceRange, index, FALSE)`

So if the value from first parameter `valueOrCell`, exists in the sourceRange, return the value at `index`. `FALSE` is to have the exact match.

In my example I'm using only a single worksheet, but if you set the sourceRange to different worksheet it works as well.

[image: example using VLOOKUP]

Comment: I want to keep the software name and its version on different columns. I'd keep the latest security-patch version number (not the latest version) for each software. At the end of the day, I want to know which software to do security upgrade. Non-security upgrade are not essential to me. So it would be a test to ">= secure version" test, not exact match test.

Comment: Also, on a brief test, it doesn't seem to support query cells in another worksheet (i.e. `'Sheet 2'!A:A`).